# Cannot create a PowerForm from the selected template in docusign

Tags: docusignapi, powerform

I'm using DocuSign developer center to create a PowerForm from a Template but I allways get the error:

> Cannot create a PowerForm from the selected template.

Do you have any idea of this issue?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 6):

Ok, the problem was that the template needs to have a recipient with the name empty. And in all cases i was adding a recipient with the name filled. I would have appreciated a more clarifying error message :-)

Answer (score 1):

To begin creating a DocuSign PowerForm you'll first need to make sure you have created a template only filling in the ​role ​field for the recipient and have left the ​email and ​name ​field blank. If your template is not set up this way DocuSign will fail to create your PowerForm.